# list is always set to be equal to another even when not called

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a loop, where a neural network is set to be equal to the best neural. Then, I change the neurons list a bit, and calculate whatever with it, but it also sets the bestNeurons list at the same time. Here's is an excerpt of my code, so you can try it:

```
for x in range(numberOfGenerations):
    print(neurons)
    print(bestNeurons)
    neurons = bestNeurons
    print(neurons)
    print(bestNeurons)  # Both lists should be the same here
    for y in range(numberOfNeurons):
        weights[y] = random.uniform(0.999, 1.001)
        neurons[y] = weights[y] * neurons[y]

    print(neurons)
    print(bestNeurons)  # They should be different here, because neurons was changed
    if currentGenerationScore > bestScore:
        print("New best score!: ", currentGenerationScore)
        for b in range(numberOfNeurons):
        bestNeurons[b] = neurons[b]
        print(bestNeurons)
        bestScore = currentGenerationScore
        print("Best set of neurons:", bestNeurons)
        bestImageScore = totalImageScore
        bestPlaceboScore = totalPlaceboScore

print(neurons)
print(bestNeurons)
```

Normally, at the end of my code block, the lists neurons and bestNeurons should be different, but by printing them in the console, they are in fact, set equal. I want the neurons list to be changed without affecting the bestNeurons list. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and turn your code into a [mre]. It cannot be run on its own at the moment. Please provide initial values for all variables.

Comment: Try `neurons = bestNeurons.copy()` or `neurons = list(bestNeurons)`.

Comment: (1) Your posted code still fails to run for at least two distinct errors.  (2) The lists are equal because you specifically set them to be the same list.  Look up how to make a copy of a list.

Comment: It worked. It seems like setting a list to be equal directly to another makes the interpreter treat it as one list. Thanks a lot, Timus.

Answer (score 0):

"Try neurons = bestNeurons.copy() or neurons = list(bestNeurons). – Timus 1 hour ago"